# Restricción para registros repetidos

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

realizo un formulario que corresponde a un horario de trabajadores. Mi formulario inserta los días y las horas sin problema alguno, lo que necesito o pretendo que haga el sistema es que revise en mi BD los registros que se encuentren y muestre una alerta que ese registro ya existe, esto ultimo quiero que se base en todos mis  campos idctg_turno,idctg_dia, hr_entrada y hr_salida es decir si ya existe el dia registrado "lunes" con hora entrada 06:00am, hora Salida 03:00 pm y mi Turno "Primero", no inserte el registro por que ya se encuentra en mi BD y que mande un mensaje.

Muchas Gracias/Saludos

```html
<html lang="es">
 <head>
 
 


<style>
div label
{
 float: left;
 width: 50%;
 
}


</style>


<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- FooTable Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="js/compiled/footable.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="js/demo-rows.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
 </head>
 
 <body>
 
 <div id="page">
   <div class="header">
    <a href="#menu"></a>
    Sistema Integral de Nómina
   </div>
   <h1 align="center">Gesti&oacute;n de Horarios</h1>
            <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Consulta de Horarios</strong>
   <a href="horario_edit.php" ><img src="images/file_get.png"  width="50" height="50" title="consultar" style="cursor:pointer"></a></p>
 
 
 
 
 
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <h3 style="text-align:center">NUEVO REGISTRO DE HORARIO</h3>
   </div>
   
   <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="guardar.php" autocomplete="off">
   
   
   
   
   
    
    
    
<div class="form-group">
<label for="idctg_turno" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Turno</label>
<?php
require("connect_db.php");

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT idctg_turno, descripcion FROM ctg_turno";
$res = $mysqli->query($query);
$option = '';
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){

    $option.="<option value=\"$row[idctg_turno]\">$row[descripcion] </option>";   
   
}
?>


<div class="col-sm-10">
      
     
<select type="text" class="form-control" id="idctg_turno" name="idctg_turno" placeholder="Turno" required     >
<option value="-">Selecciona el Turno</option>
<?php echo $option; ?>
</select><br /><br /></div></div>

    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="idctg_dia" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Día</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
       <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" id="idctg_dia[]" name="idctg_dia[]" value="1"> Lunes
         </label>
          </div>
           </div>
    
    
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="hr_entrada" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Hora Entrada</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
       <input type="time" class="form-control" id="hr_entrada" name="hr_entrada[]" placeholder="hr_entrada">
     </div>
         </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="hr_salida" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Hora Salida</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="time" class="form-control" id="hr_salida" name="hr_salida[]" placeholder="hr_salida">
        </div>
            </div><br /><br />
      
      
      
      
      
      
      <div class="form-group">
     <label for="idctg_dia" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Día</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
       <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" id="idctg_dia[]" name="idctg_dia[]" value="2"> Martes
         </label>
          </div>
           </div>
    
    
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="hr_entrada" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Hora Entrada</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
       <input type="time" class="form-control" id="hr_entrada" name="hr_entrada[]" placeholder="hr_entrada">
     </div>
         </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="hr_salida" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Hora Salida</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="time" class="form-control" id="hr_salida" name="hr_salida[]" placeholder="hr_salida">
        </div>
            </div><br /><br />
      
      
      
      
      
      
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="idctg_dia" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Día</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
       <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" id="idctg_dia[]" name="idctg_dia[]" value="3"> Miercoles
         </label>
          </div>
           </div>
    
    
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="hr_entrada" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Hora Entrada</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
       <input type="time" class="form-control" id="hr_entrada" name="hr_entrada[]" placeholder="hr_entrada">
     </div>
         </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="hr_salida" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Hora Salida</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="time" class="form-control" id="hr_salida" name="hr_salida[]" placeholder="hr_salida">
        </div>
            </div><br /><br />
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="idctg_dia" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Día</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
       <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" id="idctg_dia[]" name="idctg_dia[]" value="4"> Jueves
         </label>
          </div>
           </div>
    
    
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="hr_entrada" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Hora Entrada</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
       <input type="time" class="form-control" id="hr_entrada" name="hr_entrada[]" placeholder="hr_entrada">
     </div>
         </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="hr_salida" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Hora Salida</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="time" class="form-control" id="hr_salida" name="hr_salida[]" placeholder="hr_salida">
        </div>
            </div><br /><br />
      
      
      
      
      
      
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="idctg_dia" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Día</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
       <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" id="idctg_dia[]" name="idctg_dia[]" value="5"> Viernes
         </label>
          </div>
           </div>
    
    
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="hr_entrada" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Hora Entrada</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
       <input type="time" class="form-control" id="hr_entrada" name="hr_entrada[]" placeholder="hr_entrada">
     </div>
         </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="hr_salida" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Hora Salida</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="time" class="form-control" id="hr_salida" name="hr_salida[]" placeholder="hr_salida">
        </div>
            </div><br /><br />
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="idctg_dia" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Día</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
       <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" id="idctg_dia[]" name="idctg_dia[]" value="6"> Sabado
         </label>
          </div>
           </div>
    
    
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="hr_entrada" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Hora Entrada</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
       <input type="time" class="form-control" id="hr_entrada" name="hr_entrada[]" placeholder="hr_entrada">
     </div>
         </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="hr_salida" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Hora Salida</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="time" class="form-control" id="hr_salida" name="hr_salida[]" placeholder="hr_salida">
        </div>
            </div><br /><br />
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="idctg_dia" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Día</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
       <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" id="idctg_dia[]" name="idctg_dia[]" value="7"> Domingo
         </label>
          </div>
           </div>
    
    
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="hr_entrada" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Hora Entrada</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
       <input type="time" class="form-control" id="hr_entrada" name="hr_entrada[]" placeholder="hr_entrada">
     </div>
         </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="hr_salida" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Hora Salida</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="time" class="form-control" id="hr_salida" name="hr_salida[]" placeholder="hr_salida">
        </div>
            </div><br /><br />
      
      
      

    
    <div class="form-group">
     <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-default">Regresar</a>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
     </div>
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>
  
  <?php
     include("includes/menus.php"); ?>
     </div>
     <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
  <!--<script src="includes/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>-->
  <script src="js/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
  <script src="js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  <!-- Add in any FooTable dependencies we may need -->
  <script src="js/moment.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Add in FooTable itself -->
  <script src="js/compiled/footable.js"></script>
  <!-- Initialize FooTable -->
  <script>
   jQuery(function($){
    $('.table').footable();
   });
  </script>
  
  
 </body>
 </div>
</html>
```

```html
<?php
 
$turno = $_POST['idctg_turno'];
$entrada = $_POST['hr_entrada'];
$salida =$_POST['hr_salida'];
$arraydia = $_POST['idctg_dia'];

$total = count($arraydia);

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "admon");
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO ctg_horario (idctg_turno, hr_entrada, hr_salida, idctg_dia) VALUES (?,?,?,?)")) {
    for ($i=0; $i < $total ; $i++) { 
        //Como envía todos los valores, preguntamos si 
        // no está vacío entonces insertamos.
        if(!empty($entrada[$i]) && !empty($salida[$i])){
            $in =  date('H:i:s',strtotime($entrada[$i]));
            $out =  date('H:i:s',strtotime($salida[$i]));
           //bindeamos los parámetros para la query
            // Obteniendo el elemento del array idctg_dia
            $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $turno, $in, $out,$arraydia[$i]);
            $stmt->execute();
        }

    }   
} 
?>
<html lang="es">
 <head>
  
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="row" style="text-align:center">
     <?php if($stmt) { ?>
      <h3>REGISTRO GUARDADO</h3>
      <?php } else { ?>
      <h3>ERROR AL GUARDAR</h3>
     <?php } ?>
     
     <a href="horario.php" class="btn btn-primary">Regresar</a>
     
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear una **clave primaria compuesta** que tendrá los 4 campos que necesitas evaluar (idctg_turno, idctg_dia, hr_entrada y hr_salida) para que justamente cumplas tu cometido.

Aquí te dejo un link con un ejemplo que posee unos campos bastante parecidos a los tuyos y en el cual se crea la clave primaria compuesta: [Ejemplo clave compuesta](http://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/mysqlya/temarios/descripcion.php?cod=38&punto=39&inicio=)

Aquí tienes más ejemplos que solucionan el problema de registros repetidos como lo has planteado con clave primaria compuesta: [MySQL clave primaria compuesta](http://jjmojicamysql.blogspot.com/2012/05/39-clave-primaria-compuesta.html)

Por lo que tu tabla **ctg_horario** debería quedar con una clave primaria compuesta de este estilo:

```
create table ctg_horario(
  idctg_turno tipodedato not null,
  idctg_dia tidpodedato not null,
  hr_entrada tipodedato not null
  hr_salida tipodedato not null,
  primary key(idctg_turno,idctg_dia,hr_entrada,hr_salida)
 );
```

Espero te sea de utilidad. Un Saludo!

Answer (score 1):

Otra opción es usar el tipo de [índice único](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html) que tiene MySQL (Unique Key) y mantenemos el índice primario para su uso particular, crear una relación con índice primario compuesto te obligará a que las tablas foraneas tengan tambíen la misma cantidad de columnas, y le estás añadiendo más complegidad. Te dejo un ejemplo de como se hace:

```
CREATE TABLE ctg_horarios (
  id          BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  idctg_turno BIGINT NOT NULL,
  idctg_dia   BIGINT NOT NULL,
  hr_entrada  BIGINT NOT NULL,
  hr_salida   BIGINT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id),
  UNIQUE KEY ctg_horarios_uidx (idctg_turno, idctg_dia, hr_entrada, hr_salida)
);
```

El índice único mantiene la **unicidad de los registros** y tambien funciona como un indice normal para **optimizar las busquedas**.